# How to get recursive groups of an Active Directory user via Python Script, in a easy, fast and safe way?

Tags: python, linux, active-directory, ldap

My current logic is as below.

- Take **username** and **domain name**.
  Loop over each **domain controller** in that domain and get the user entry.
  Consider the **latest entry** from all of them based on `whenChanged` timestamp that we always capture, and fetch the user groups i.e. `memberOf` from it.
- For each **user group**,
  loop over each **domain controller** in the domain and get the group entry.
  Consider the **latest entry** from all of them, and fetch the group's sub groups i.e. `memberOf` field. (Do this recursively.)
- Send the final list back to user.

**Note:**
There are also cases of `duplicacy` and there might be rare chances of **infinite loop** also, say where groups A is present in B and B is present in A.
Hence, if a group is looked up once, it should not be looked again.

My config is like below.

```
{
"domain_controllers":
    ["abc.domainname.companyname.com",
    "pqr.domainname.companyname.com"],
"name": "domainname",
"user": "*",
"password": "*",
"base_dn": "DC=domainname,DC=companyname,DC=com"
}
```

My current code is as below. But it is very time consumung.

```
def get_latest_entry(self, domain_name, data_type, ldap_query):
    domain = self.config.get_domain(domain_name)
    ldap_attrs = ["memberOf", "whenChanged"]
    ldap_entries_for_all_dcs = []
    for hostname in domain.domain_controllers:
        with "<<ldap_connection>>":
            try:
                ldap_connection.search(serahc_base=domain.base_dn, search_filter=ldap_query, attributes=ldap_attrs)
            except ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPInvalidFilterError:
                return None
            if not ldap_connection.entries:
                continue
            json_entry = <<self.converttojson>>(ldap_connection.entries[0]))
            if json_entry["memberOf"]:
                json_entry["memberOf"] = [str(memberOf.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')) for memberOf in json_entry["memberOf"]]
                ldap_entries_for_all_dcs.append(json_entry)
    return max(ldap_entries_for_all_dcs,
               key=lambda ldap_entry: ldap_entry['whenChanged'])["memberOf"] if ldap_entries_for_all_dcs else None
```

```
def get_user_groups(self, sam_account_name, domain_name):
    return self.get_latest_entry(domain_name=domain_name, data_type="user", ldap_query="(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={}))".format(sam_account_name))
```

```
def get_sub_groups(self, distinguished_name, domain_name):
    return self.get_latest_entry(domain_name=domain_name, data_type="group", ldap_query="(&(objectCategory=Group)(objectClass=Group)(distinguishedName={}))".format( distinguished_name))
```

```
def get_recursive_groups(self, sam_account_name, domain_name):
    def nestedgrouplookup(distinguished_name, domain_name):
        if distinguished_name not in recursive_groups_list:
            recursive_groups_list.append(distinguished_name)
            nested_list = self.get_sub_groups(distinguished_name, domain_name)
            if nested_list:
                for memberOf in nested_list:
                    nestedgrouplookup(memberOf, domain_name)
    recursive_groups_list = []
    user_groups_list = self.get_user_groups(sam_account_name, domain_name)
    if not user_groups_list:
        return []
    for distinguished_name in user_groups_list:
        nestedgrouplookup(distinguished_name, domain_name)
    return recursive_groups_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For groups within Microsoft Active Directory you can use a single query and no need to query all Domain Controllers.

To get [All Groups a User is a member of including Nested Groups](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+User+Related+Searches-AllGroupsAUserIsAMemberOfIncludingNestedGroups) use a filter similar to:

```
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(CN=UserName,CN=Users,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET))
```

Will return all groups that the user is a member of including nested groups.

There are a few limitations but none that most people would ever run into.

Comment: `ldap_query = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=*,CN=Users,DC=am,DC=sony,DC=com))"  
##### Also tried with ldap_query = "(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=*,CN=Users,DC=am,DC=sony,DC=com)"  
###### Also tried exact CN username in both ldap queries  
###### Its Just printing [] for all DCs, but user does have groups and sub groups, as checked manually`

Comment: `for hostname in <<domain.domain_controllers>>:  
 tls = ldap3.Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_NONE, version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
 server = ldap3.Server(hostname, get_info=ldap3.ALL, mode=ldap3.IP_V4_PREFERRED, tls=tls, use_ssl=True)
 with ldap3.Connection(server=server, authentication=ldap3.NTLM, auto_bind=True, password=xx, read_only=True, receive_timeout=30,user=yy) as ldap_connection:
  search_parameters = {'search_base': domain.base_dn, 'search_filter': ldap_query, 'attributes': ['*']}
  ldap_connection.search(**search_parameters)
  print(ldap_connection.entries)`

Comment: As I said, "no need to query all Domain Controllers."

Comment: Thanks a lot. Apart from searching redundantly, I think my distinguishedName was not matching malformed and not matchin my data, hence no results.  
Now I am getting ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketReceiveError: error receiving data: The read operation timed out. I will probably get help on it separately.